# Can Apache Spark and Oracle co exist

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, bigdata

I would like to take some XML data stored in Oracle database and do parsing of certain values using Apache Spark and store in another table in the same machine.

If so, 
What parameters and configurations do I need to set it up for SPARK and ORacle to co exist in a single LINUX box.

Comment: why do u want to downvote ,its a valid question

Comment: What problems are you experiencing?

Comment: I would like to set it up from scratch,is there a way to do that ,if so what would be the parameters and the order to install it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can definitely have Apache Spark and Oracle in one machine.

> What parameters and configurations do I need to set

Assuming you use `oracle-jdbc` to connect to Oracle through Spark:

- Just install/start oracle as a standalone database (it doesn't need any additional configurations)
- There are no additional Configurations required for Spark as well (other than basic confs)

Only thing that is required is adding `oracle-jdbc.jar` in Spark's Classpath, and you are ready to query on oracle through spark.